# Why can't mma be drawn in continuous form with the Fibonacci number general formula?

Tags: plotting

Of course, I know I can use `Plot` and `DiscretePlot` plot the built-in `Fibonacci[x]`, but why this code don't work?

We can find the formula in wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#:%7E:text=1%7D%2C%5Cend%7Baligned%7D%7D%7D-,From%20this,-%2C%20the%20nth%20element):

```
Plot[1/Sqrt[5] (((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^x - ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^x), {x, 0, 26}]
```

[image]

Is it a bug of MMA?

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is only valid for integer `x`

```
FunctionDomain[
  1/Sqrt[5] (((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^x - ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^x), x]

(* Element[x, Integers] *)
```

The correct expression for arbitrary real `x` is

```
f[x_] = Fibonacci[x] // FunctionExpand

(* ((1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^x - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^x Cos[π x])/Sqrt[5] *)

% // FullSimplify

(* (2^-x ((1 + Sqrt[5])^x - (-1 + Sqrt[5])^x Cos[π x]))/Sqrt[5] *)

Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: I know we can plot `Fibonacci[x]`, I just don't know why I cannot plot my that formula.. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not the right function for the Fibonacci numbers. Especially, you use the term

```
 ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^x)
```

but $ (1 - Sqrt[5])/2)<0 $

The power function with negative base is not real for general real $ x $

The correct way is

```
Plot[1/Sqrt[5]* (((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^x - ((-1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^x), {x, 1, 26}]
```

with the result

[image]

Comment: Look wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#:~:text=1%7D%2C%5Cend%7Baligned%7D%7D%7D-,From%20this,-%2C%20the%20nth%20element)

Comment: Why the base cannot be less than 0?

Comment: OK, I am correcting: Your function is defined for integer x only, but in that case, it does not support the Plot function. The better version is

ListPlot[(1/Sqrt[5] (((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^# - ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^#)) & /@ 
  Range[0, 26]]

Answer (score 1):

You have these two expressions in your plot.

```
t = List @@ (1/Sqrt[5] ((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^x - 
    1/Sqrt[5] ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^x)
```

$$\left\{-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^x}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)\right)^x}{\sqrt{5}}\right\}$$

The second one can be plotted for x < 0; but consider:

```
t[[1]] /. x -> 0.4 // N
```

> -0.113999 - 0.350854 I

So you cannot `Plot` this complex number.

Comment: Thanks very very much

Answer (score 0):

I can `Plot` it by add a `Re` now

```
Plot[Re[1/Sqrt[5] (((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^x - ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^x)], {x, 1, 25}]
```

[image]

Comment: So, why `Re` and not `Abs`, `Re+Im`? Looks like an arbitrary question (because it is not specified in what sense the interpolation should be given). Also, looks like an arbitrary answer (because not explained why certain choice is made).